# php Declare a variable by type held in a string

Tags: php

I am trying to declare an object by the value held in a string. So if a string holds 'Class1' i want to declare it by type Class1.

Something like this

```
$CT = "Class1";
if (class_exists($CT))
    $MyClass = new Type($CT);
```

I can do something like the following, but would rather do it as above if possible.

```
if (isset($_GET["CT"]))
    $CT = $_GET["CT"];
else
    $CT = "Class1";

echo "CT = " . $CT . "<br>";

switch ($CT)
{
    case "Class1":
        $MyClass = new Class1;
        break;

    case "Class2":
        $MyClass = new Class2;
        break;

    default:
        $MyClass = new Class1;
    
}

echo $MyClass->Result();

class Class1
{
    function Result()
    {
        return "I am Class 1";
    }
}

class Class2
{
    function Result()
    {
        return "I am Class 2";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what that `Type` thing should be, but `$MyClass = new $CT;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use variables after the `new` keyword:

```php
$CT = "Class1";
if (class_exists($CT))
    $MyClass = new $CT();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can most assuredly create a class instance by its name alone, so your code would be

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["CT"]))
    $CT = $_GET["CT"];
else
    $CT = "Class1";

echo "CT = " . $CT . "<br>";

$instance = new $CT();

echo $instance->Result();

class Class1
{
    function Result()
    {
        return "I am Class 1";
    }
}

class Class2
{
    function Result()
    {
        return "I am Class 2";
    }
}
```

See it in action [here](http://jdoodle.com/ia/9Es)